# Which is the correct verb for ‘to correct (straighten) one’s uniform’?

Tags: translation, verb

Using zKorean, I came across numerous entries when searching for the verb ‘to correct’:

- 정정하다 (jeongjeonghada)
- 정오하다 (jeong-o-hada)
- 첨삭하다 (cheomsaghada)
- 교정하다 (gyojeonghada)
- 수정하다 (sujeonghada)
- 보정하다 (bojeonghada)

What I want to express is ‘Straighten [your] uniforms!’ or ‘Correct [your] uniforms’ as a command. What is the difference in usage between the verbs listed, and are any of them the correct phrase used in military contexts? If not, what is the correct military command given to order soldiers to straighten their uniforms?*

* If such a command is not given, an order might be the better option. For clarity: I understand a command as a brief imperative given for a group of soldiers to perform an action simultaneously, such as ‘차렷!’, whilst an order is a complex set of instructions for a task to be undertaken, such as ‘Retake that hill by executing a pincer movement on the opposing force; execute at 0400 hours.’

* I would suggest adding [military](/questions/tagged/military), but do not have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Those words you listed all sound formal. In military contexts, words tend to be brief.

I believe the nonstandard (that is, slangy) idiom “**각(을) 잡다**” (“to set the edges”) is commonly used for military uniforms:

> “**군복 각 잡아!**” (literally, “Set the proper edges for your military uniform!”)

---

- “군복” — “military uniform” (noun)
- “각” (角) — “edge” (noun)
- “을” — An optional object marker. (particle)
- “잡다” — “to hold; to set; to have; to get; …” (verb)

Comment: Should I read 角 as 을? And also, do I understand you correctly that the command excludes the object marker?

Comment: @CannedMan No, and yes. The “을” is an optional object marker; it is almost always omitted in speech. “[角](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A7%92)” is the Chinese character for the word “각;” I added it as a subscript to explain the meaning of the word.